# get next element that have same name class jsoup in android studio

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

i want to get next element that have same name class in html. html tag is like :

**html:**

```
  <section class="post">
        <img class="pecintakomik" src="/images/top/op.jpg" alt="pecintakomik.com" />
            <div class="post-cnt">
                <h2>Manga bla bla</h2>
                    <ul>
                    <li><strong>Nama Alternatif:</strong> </li>
                    <li><strong>Tahun Rilis:</strong> 2010</li>
                    <li><strong>Author(s):</strong> sensei1
                    <li><strong>Artist(s):</strong> sense2</li>
                    <li><strong>Genre:</strong> Action</li>
                    <li><strong>Sinopsis:</strong> bla bla bla </li>
                    <li><span class='st_facebook_hcount' displayText='Facebook'></span> <span class='st_twitter_hcount' displayText='Tweet'></span> <span class='st_sharethis_hcount' displayText='ShareThis'></span></li>                      
                    </ul>
            </div>
                <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
    </section>
    <img src="http://www.pecintakomik.com/images/block.png">
    <section class="post">
        <div class="post-cnt">
            <h2>List Chapter(s)</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/manga/bla_bla/816"> bla bl 816 <img src="/images/new.gif"><em>Baca Online </em></a></li>
                <li><a href="/manga/bla_bla/815"> bla bla 815<em>Baca Online </em></a></li>
                <li><a href="/manga/bla_bla/814"> bla bla 814<em>Baca Online </em></a></li>
                <li><a href="/manga/bla_bla/813"> bla bla 813<em>Baca Online </em></a></li>
            </ul>
       </div>
    </section>
```

my code is to get href link of list manga(and store it on sqllite), but i can't get it:

**java code:**

```
private List<Chapter> parseHtmlToChapters(RequestWrapper request, String unparsedHtml) {
    int beginIndex = unparsedHtml.indexOf("<div class=\"post-cnt\">");
    int endIndex = unparsedHtml.indexOf("</div>", beginIndex);

    String trimmedHtml = unparsedHtml.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);

    Document parsedDocument = Jsoup.parse(trimmedHtml);


    List<Chapter> chapterList = scrapeChaptersFromParsedDocument(parsedDocument);
    chapterList = setSourceForChapterList(chapterList);
    chapterList = setParentUrlForChapterList(chapterList, request.getUrl());
    chapterList = setNumberForChapterList(chapterList);

    saveChaptersToDatabase(chapterList, request.getUrl());

    return chapterList;
}

private List<Chapter> scrapeChaptersFromParsedDocument(Document parsedDocument) {
    List<Chapter> chapterList = new ArrayList<Chapter>();

    Element chapterElementnya = parsedDocument.select("div.post-cnt").get(1);
    Elements chapterElements = chapterElementnya.getElementsByTag("li");


    for (Element chapterElement : chapterElements) {
        Chapter currentChapter = constructChapterFromHtmlBlock(chapterElement);

        chapterList.add(currentChapter);
    }

    return chapterList;
}

private Chapter constructChapterFromHtmlBlock(Element chapterElement) {
    Chapter newChapter = DefaultFactory.Chapter.constructDefault();

    Element urlElement = chapterElement.select("a").first();
    Element nameElement = chapterElement.select("a").first();

    if (urlElement != null) {
        String fieldUrl = "http://www.pecintakomik.com" + urlElement.attr("href");
        newChapter.setUrl(fieldUrl);
    }
    if (nameElement != null) {
        String fieldName = nameElement.text();
        newChapter.setName(fieldName);
    }

    boolean fieldNew = chapterElement.html().contains("<img src=\"/images/new.gif\">");
    newChapter.setNew(fieldNew);

    return newChapter;
}
```

please anyone know how i can get list of second class that have same name?

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
private List<Chapter> parseHtmlToChapters(RequestWrapper request, String unparsedHtml) {
    int beginIndex = unparsedHtml.indexOf("<div class=\"post-cnt\">");
    int endIndex = unparsedHtml.indexOf("</div>", beginIndex);

    String trimmedHtml = unparsedHtml.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
    ...
}
```

Keeps only the first list. The `trimmedHtml` will contain this:

```
<div class="post-cnt">
    <h2>Manga bla bla</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><strong>Nama Alternatif:</strong> </li>
        <li><strong>Tahun Rilis:</strong> 2010</li>
        <li><strong>Author(s):</strong> sensei1
        <li><strong>Artist(s):</strong> sense2</li>
        <li><strong>Genre:</strong> Action</li>
        <li><strong>Sinopsis:</strong> bla bla bla </li>
        <li><span class='st_facebook_hcount' displayText='Facebook'></span> <span class='st_twitter_hcount' displayText='Tweet'></span> <span class='st_sharethis_hcount' displayText='ShareThis'></span></li>                      
    </ul>
</div>
```

To keep both lists, you can do this:

```
int beginIndex = unparsedHtml.indexOf("<div class=\"post-cnt\">");
int secondListStart = unparsedHtml.indexOf("<div class=\"post-cnt\">",beginIndex + "<div class=\"post-cnt\">".length());
int endIndex = unparsedHtml.indexOf("</div>", secondListStart) + "</div>".length();

String trimmedHtml = unparsedHtml.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
```

but it will be much safer to parse the entire page. To do that, change:

```
Document parsedDocument = Jsoup.parse(trimmedHtml);
```

To:

```
Document parsedDocument = Jsoup.parse(unparsedHtml);
```

Comment: how i can get second <div class="post-cnt">? not the first one <div class="post-cnt">. and why parse entire page is much safer?

Comment: @poundPound Parsing the entire page is safer because HTML syntax is not that strict which means that `indexOf("<div class=\"post-cnt\">")` will fail if the HTML code contains extra spaces or uses `'`  instead of `"` as quotes or who knows what else, `Jsoup` deals with all of this. To get only the second list, you can use: `String trimmedHtml = unparsedHtml.substring(secondListStart, endIndex);`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private List<Chapter> parseHtmlToChapters(RequestWrapper request, String unparsedHtml) {

    Document parsedDocument = Jsoup.parse(unparsedHtml);

    List<Chapter> chapterList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Element a : parsedDocument.select("div.post-cnt a")) {
        Chapter newChapter = DefaultFactory.Chapter.constructDefault();
        newChapter.setUrl("http://www.pecintakomik.com" + a.attr("href"));
        newChapter.setName(a.text());
        newChapter.setNew(!a.select("img[src=/images/new.gif]").isEmpty());
        chapterList.add(newChapter);
    }
    // .....
```

`parsedDocument.select("div.post-cnt a")` selects all `<a>` elements under all `<div class="post-cnt">` elements.  There are four such elements in your sample HTML.